# Определение ботов по частоте заходов и ip

Tags: php, ip, бот

Столкнулся с ситуацией, когда на несуществующие страницы в течении короткого промежутка времени заходят с одного ip адреса. Т.к все запросы обрабатываются PHP скриптом (ЧПУ) то возник вопрос как отследить таких ботов и забанить их на некоторое время.

Думаю создать таблицу с временем посещения и IP адресом пользователя который зашёл на несуществующую страницу и анализировать его последние посещения, если в какой-то промежуток времени заходов больше 5 то добавить бота в бан-лист.

Пишу вопрос тут, поскольку интересно, есть ли готовые примеры подобного механизма, если да то скиньте ссылки, пожалуйста.

Comment: Заодно проверь сайт на известные уязвимости - это скорее всего не просто боты, а вирусы/сканеры уязвимостей пытаются взломать сайт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать более серьезные метода. Например `fail2ban`. Нашел ссылку на [мануал](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Talk:Apache), правда на англ. языке...

Эта штука позволяет заблокировать на уровне iptables нежелаемые IP. Чаще используется для блокировки брутфорса SSH, но судя по статье, может гибко настраиваться для Apache.

К сожалению этот вариант не подойдет, если у вас shared-хостинг...

Comment: Использую fail2ban для блокировки брутфорса ssh, однако я не совсем понимаю как из пхп скрипта записывать в логи апача 404 ошибку.

Comment: на php это делается через header: `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");`

Comment: Да, но при этом в логи апача ничего не пишется, потому как скрипт отработал, всё ок.
Или же в настройках апача надо что-то указать?

Comment: В логи Apache будет в любом случае занесено это посещение, его HTTP-код будет 404, конечно, если вы не меняли настройки логирования.

Comment: спасибо, проверю.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал не обращать внимание.
Этот мусор будет всегда - и с одного айпи, и с разных. И с известными паттернами, типа поиска админки вордпресса и пхпмайадмина, и с полной белибердой.
Это интернет, и такое будет всегда.

Вместо борьбы с ветряными мельницами лучше сделать что-то действительно полезное на сайте.

Comment: Тут не столько борьба, сколько хочется их определять. Просто у меня обо всех ошибка на сайте приходят письма на почту. Вот чтобы такого объёма спама не было, я и хочу отсеивать этих ботов